# How to speed up the search for matching values in a second data frame in a line-by-line iteration over a first data frame?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas

I have a survey response dataframe for which each survey has a `code`:

`df`

```
    code    item_stamp          question_name   question_type   scorable_question   subquestion_name    stage    products_stamp product_ID  answer_name respondent_id   answers_identity    answer  Test Code
0   006032  '173303553131045'   Age group       single          1.0                 NaN                 Screener NaN            <NA>        31 - 45 '173303561331047'   '11357427731020'    2   6032
1   006032  '173303553131045'   Age group       single          1.0                 NaN                 Screener NaN            <NA>        31 - 45 '173303561431047'   '11357427731020'    2   6032
```

I also have a dataframe with the types of each survey that are identified with `Test Code` :

`df_synthesis_clean`

```
    Country Country Code    Category            Application                 Gender  Program         Evaluation Stage                    Context Packaging Code  Test Code   Test Completion Agency Deadline Product Type    Line Extension  Dosage  Fragrance House_ID  product_ID  Liking Mean Liking Scale    Olfactive Family    Olfactive Subfamily OLFACTIVE CLUSTER EASY FRESH TEXTURED WARM  SIGNATURE   QUALIFICATION VERT ORANGE ROUGE TOP SELLER  TOP TESTER
0   France  FR              Fine Men Fragrances Perf/Edt/A-Shave/Col (FM)   M       scent hunter    clst - sniff - on glass ball jar    Blind   NaN             3879         4/15/2016 0:00 NaN Market Product  EDT 12.0    817.0   8082451124  5.55    0 to 10 WOODY   Floral  TEXTURED WARM   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   USA     US              Fine Men Fragrances Perf/Edt/A-Shave/Col (FM)   M       scent hunter    clst - sniff - on glass ball jar    Blind   NaN             3855         4/15/2016 0:00 NaN Market Product  EDT 12.0    817.0   8082451124  4.88    0 to 10 WOODY   Floral  TEXTURED WARM   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I want to add a column about the type of Program that caused the response (Flash or non-flash).

I have the test id in df and the test type in `df_synthesis_clean`. So I tried in a Google collaboratory without GPU (because I don't know how to use it):

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
  # I will look in the df_synthesis_clean table to see if the row['code'] corresponds to a Test Code.
  # I have to put iloc 0 because a study corresponds to several tested products but the respuestas no tienen  
  program = df_synthesis_clean.loc[df_synthesis_clean['Test Code'] == row['code']].iloc[0]['Program']
  row['Program'] = program
```

It works on small amount of data but unfortunately I now have more than **three million lines** in `df` so that's why it takes a long time.

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the rows of a data frame is usually very slow.
For combining the values of two data frames you can instead use [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) like this

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['Test Code', 'Program']
pd.merge(df, df_synthesis_clean[cols], left_on='code', right_on='Test Code')
```

When using `pd.merge`, take care to choose the correct value for the optional parameter `how`. By default, only the rows corresponding to keys that are present in both data frames will be part of the resulting data frame. But you might want to change that according to your needs.

Please let me know if it works. Unfortunately, I cannot test my code at the moment.